# navigation bar buttons not working because it's not the initial scene in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i transferred from View Controller A to View Controller B with this code

```
UIViewController *HomePageView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePageView"];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[HomePageView] animated:YES];
// The above code transfers the user from the A to B after verification.
```

Now i am trying to connect a view controller B to view controller C with a push segue. The button that does the action is a navigation bar button,but anytime i try to click on the button it doesn't respond. I also think I'm have this problem because view controller B is not my initial scene. Any ideas on what i can do?
Please view picture link to have an idea. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijWjl.png

Comment: "i transferred from View Controller A to View Controller B": Do you want it as using Push Segue or just Modal ?

Comment: Thanks Bhole. The connection of View Controller A to View Controller B is actually fine. The problem is connecting from B to C. i want to use Push Segue.

Comment: You said - "I also think I'm have this problem because view controller B is not my initial scene". You're wrong here. It doesn't matter whether it's first or second or any view. I must work.

Comment: The Problem here is setViewControllers:animated:. Have you read the documentation for this method - "Replaces the view controllers currently managed by the navigation controller with the specified items." Means it remove all view controllers in the stack, including C, and there is only B in the stack. So, no segue to C.

Comment: And first of all there is no connection between A & B, neither push nor modal, and both have different Navigation Controllers. I think you should use 'Modal' way to load B on A.

Comment: thanks for the help, I am new to Objective c. Can you please show me the code to make View Controller B push to View Controller C ?

Comment: So, is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: No. My page A which the initial page, is a login in page. so if a user login credentials is valid, it connects them to Page B without any link back. This Works Fine with this code   UIViewController *HomePageView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePageView"];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[HomePageView] animated:YES];
// The above code transfers the user from the A to B after verification.        but when trying to link Page B to Page C with push segue, i discovered that the buttons on the navigation bar in Page are not functional.

Comment: what can i do to make sure that the navigation buttons are functional?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
[self presentViewController:HomePageView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in place of:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[HomePageView] animated:YES];
```

(if you don't want to go back from B to A).